# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-fullcalendar'

Tags: angular

i installed the ng-fullcalendar and fullcalendar, but when i import FullCalendarModule in the app.module.ts, the error shows "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-fullcalendar'"[error-img-shows-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su5ko.png)

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {EventService} from './event.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FullCalendarModule} from 'ng-fullcalendar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [EventService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the module using `npm install --save ng-fullcalendar@latest` as the module wasn't saved properly. I did this and my module ran as it should.
Also add

`"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.0.1",
 "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.0.1",
 "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.0.1",`

to your `package.json` and run `npm install` && 'ng serve'. You will be fine

Comment: do u have facebook? The package.json is so long, the editor didnt allow me to post the package.json file